# Too many rerenders in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to setState in return satetement in function, but i got the error: too many rerrenders. How to avoid this in my case?

```js
    const [selectedItems, setState] = React.useState([]);
      const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([]);
      const handleChange = selectedItems => {
        setState(selectedItems);
      };

      const search = selectedItems => {
        selectedItems =
          selectedItems.length < 2
            ? selectedItems.join(",").toLowerCase()
            : selectedItems
                .slice(selectedItems.length - 1)
                .join(",")
                .toLowerCase();
        let arrayOfMatchedObjects = elements.filter(object => {
          return JSON.stringify(object)
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(selectedItems);
        });

        return setArr(arrayOfMatchedObjects); //here i setSate
      };
```

link: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-frost-skle2

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line:

```
  console.log(search(selectedItems));
```

and see the error gone.
It happens because basically inside render you are calling `search` - which sets a state and causes a re render (hence the loop).
Doesn't matter in this case that you return it from function (though it is weird why you want to return it that way).

Comment: ok, but, how in another way to set the state. The idea of the app is to search  by name and if the name  is in my array to  grab the object that corespond sto the name and to add in the state. The problem appear when i  insert all 3 name in the input, because  i cant access all object, in the console i return only one - the last name I want to create a btn ant to save all objects that corresponds to the names if i add in the input 3. Do you know hoe to do this?

Comment: @Asking Sorry it is unclear what you want. I suggest you create a new question and describe there clearly what you want and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

OK one thing which stands out is you have this declared

```
const [selectedItems, setState] = React.useState([]);
```

Then right after you have

```
  const handleChange = selectedItems => {
    setState(selectedItems);
  };
```

To me that is a little ambiguous in the function handleChange which of the two 'selectedItems' will be called in setState.  I.e the variable being passed in or the variable declared in useState.

Fix this first!